# Simple Dropdown appended to dynamic div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am trying to a a drop down to a dynamically created div.
But it is not letting me to change the value, i think it's not getting focused.

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    wrapper = jQuery("<div />", {
        "class": "class1",
            "id": "dynamic1",
            "style": "background-color:beige; border:1px solid red;width:94%;",
            "text": "dynamically added div"
    }).appendTo($("#sample"));

    $('body').on("click", "#dynamic1", function () {
        $(this).html($("#changeUserform").html());
    });
});
```

I have implemented a sample fiddle to demonstrate my problem.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/X2SPM/)

Drop down will open by clicking the newly created div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `ON click` event and fire it only once !

`$('body').one("click", "#dynamic1", function () {`

I believe it should work !

Check your  [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2SPM/6/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, everytime you click on dropdown, click event of div is generated. which causes the new dropdown to be added. Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    wrapper = jQuery("<div />", {
        "class": "class1",
            "id": "dynamic1",
            "style": "background-color:beige; border:1px solid red;width:94%;",
            "text": "dynamically added div"
    }).appendTo($("#sample"));
  $("#sample").append($("<input/>", {
    type: "button",
    value: "add",
    id: "dynamic2"
}));

    $('body').on("click", "#dynamic2", function () {

        $("#dynamic1").html($("#changeUserform").html());
    });
});
```

Or you should unbind the click event from that event after the first click. USe `off` for that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    wrapper = jQuery("<div />", {
        "class": "class1",
            "id": "dynamic1",
            "style": "background-color:beige; border:1px solid red;width:94%;",
            "text": "dynamically added div"
    }).appendTo($("#sample"));

    $('body').on("click", "#dynamic1", function () {

        $("#dynamic1").html($("#changeUserform").html());
        $('body').off("click", "#dynamic1");
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2SPM/7/)

Comment: you are right, the click get bubbled up to the div again.

Answer (score 1):

This code is the problem:

```
$('body').on("click", "#dynamic1", function () {
        $(this).html($("#changeUserform").html());
});
```

Whenever you are clicking the div, you are overwriting the existing html, which is the problem

Change the `click` event to `dblclick`, though now, you have to double click it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/X2SPM/4/